# Any Appexchange app which can perform address validation on custom object address fields?

Tags: appexchange, address

Looking for appexchange solution which can do real-time or on-demand address validation on custom object address fields.  Already looked at address doctor, which validates the address on Leads, Accounts and Contacts only.  We have a custom Address object on which we would like this service to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a proven works product address validation and country complete.Have used in past ,works well.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000002zt9uEAA

Comment: This works like a charm - on custom objects.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Address Verification tool in DemandTools.  It works well.  DemandTools is listed in Appexchange, but be aware that it is a standalone application for Windows.  Account, contact, and lead are the only object types this tool lists for checking.

If nobody shares a way to validate an address in a custom object, you could consider copying your custom object data to contact records.  Use a new record type for these special contact records and keep them hidden from most users.  Keep the ID of the custom object record in these special contacts records so you can easily move the changes back to the custom object records.

Note: Address verification in DemandTools requires a purchase from StrikeIron of some number of address validations in addition to purchasing DemandTools.

I have no connection to DemandTools, CrmFusion, or StrikeIron.  I'm a satisfied customer.